# InfoPath form: How to display value in a text box based on selection in previous drop down field

Tags: infopath, form, conditional

I have a form with a field in it called TypeOfCare.  users can select five values from this menu:

```
'Residential'
'Residential EMI'
'Nursing'
'Nursing EMI'
'Care At Home'
```

Depending on what user selects from that list I want to display specific currency value in a text box entitled 'ContractRate'

Essentially:

```
IF TypeOfCare = "Residential" THEN Contract Rate displays £400
IF TypeOfCare = "Residential EMI" THEN Contract Rate displays £500
```

And so on..

Any help would be gratefully received..

Answer (score 1):

- In InfoPath designer > click on `TypeOfCare` field.
- From Properties tab > add a rule as the following.

[image]

- In rule details, In the first field Specify if the value `Residential`
- At field specify the field to set.
- At value specify the rate display that is 500

[image]

- Repeat the above steps with other conditions.

Comment: Hi @Leeroycal , Are you faced any issue to apply the above steps! please don't hesitate to tell me if you need more clarification. Also please check http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour to get Informed badge and know how to mark correct answers if it helped to solve your issue!